# how do I get a cell's location as a range in excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel

i'm trying to lookup an email in a column, then use that email's location to find other information in the relevant row.  here's my code so far:

```
Dim wsUsers As Worksheet            
Set wsUsers = Worksheets("userOutput.csv")
Dim userRows As Integer
userRows = wsUsers.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim userEmail As Range

Dim userEmailColumn As Range
Set userEmailColumn = wsUsers.Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(userRows, 4))
Dim findEmail As Variant
Set findEmail = userEmailColumn.Find("test@test.com")

Dim userEmailAd As Range
Set userEmailAd = findEmail.Address
MsgBox userEmailAd
stop
```

I'm getting `runtime error 424, object required` and it highlights the line: `Set userEmailAd = findEmail.Address`

How do I get a range so I can then use offset to find other information in the row?  Or, is there a better way?  I'm not using vlookup because column is not the first one in the overall range.

Comment: Your code, and its order, are very hard to read in this (custom) two-column format. I suggest that you edit it to make it easier for someone to assist you.

Comment: I don't believe you want `Set userEmailAd`. Take off the `Set` there.

Comment: Andy G , changed formatting per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
userRows = wsUsers.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set userEmailColumn = wsUsers.Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(userRows, 4))
```

should rather be:

```
userRows = wsUsers.Cells(wsUsers.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set userEmailColumn = wsUsers.Range(wsUsers.Cells(2, 4), wsUsers.Cells(userRows, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making the findEmail variable a variant, then just assigning it to a new variable that holds the range?

You are getting the error because the .Address property of a range is a string.  Do you want userEmailAd to be a range (object) or a string that names the range (string)?  Based on your question, you want to make it a range, so I'd change it to this:

```
Dim wsUsers As Worksheet
Set wsUsers = Worksheets("userOutput.csv")
Dim userRows As Integer
userRows = wsUsers.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim userEmail As Range

Dim userEmailColumn As Range
Set userEmailColumn = wsUsers.Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(userRows, 5))
Dim findEmail As Range
Set findEmail = userEmailColumn.Find("test@test.com")

Dim userEmailAd As Range
Set userEmailAd = findEmail
MsgBox userEmailAd.Address
Stop
```